# How can I write a LaTex command with 'if'-'then'-'else'?

Tags: conditionals, loops

I read *[LaTeX \if condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286902/latex-if-condition)* and *[How to write if and then in algorithm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540053/how-to-write-if-and-then-in-algorithm)*, but so far it did not ring a bell for me.

I am trying to create a command named *dottedSkill* like below.
The logic behind it is:

- receive two parameters
- iterate over the counter x from 1 to #2
- if my counter filled is > 0, I draw a full dot and decrement the counter
- else I draw an empty dot

```
\newcommand{\dottedSkill}[2]{
    %parameter 1 the filled dots
    %parameter 2 the max dots

    \newcounter{x}
    \newcounter{filled}
    \setcounter{filled}{#1}
    \forloop{x}{1}{\value{x} <= #2}
    {
        \ifnum \filled<1
            \Circle
        \else
            \CIRCLE
            \addtocounter{filled}{-1}
        \fi
    }
}%
```

I am not sure if the problem is with the command definition or someplace else, but when I call it on my file I get:

- Undefined control sequence. \dottedSkill{2}{9}.
- Missing number, treated as zero. \dottedSkill{2}{9}
- Undefined control sequence. \dottedSkill{2}{9}.
- Missing number, treated as zero. \dottedSkill{2}{9}

Is my function properly written?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current problem with your setup is that you're defining the `filled` counter *every* time you run `\dottedSkill`. You should pull these definitions out of your `\dottedSkill` command.

Also, you should just draw the filled circles, followed by the empty circles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand{\Circle}{\textbullet}
\newcommand{\CIRCLE}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\dottedSkill}[2]{%
  %parameter 1 the filled dots
  %parameter 2 the max dots  
  \multido{\ix=1+1}{#1}{\Circle}%
  \ifnum#1<#2 \multido{\ix=#1+1}{\numexpr#2-#1}{\CIRCLE}\fi
}%

\begin{document}

\dottedSkill{2}{9}

\dottedSkill{0}{9}

\dottedSkill{10}{9}

\dottedSkill{5}{9}

\end{document}
```

[`multido`](//ctan.org/pkg/multido) works similar to [`forloop`](//ctan.org/pkg/forloop) to iterate over some value.

Comment: It works although I had to do tiny changes since the textbullet is not the same type as circ.

So I did that
\newcommand{\EmptyDot}{\Circle}
\newcommand{\FilledDot}{$\CIRCLE$}

\newcommand{\dottedSkill}[2]{%
 %parameter 1 the filled dots
 %parameter 2 the max dots  
 \multido{\ix=1+1}{#1}{\FilledDot}%
 \ifnum#1<#2 \multido{\ix=#1+1}{\numexpr#2-#1}{\EmptyDot}\fi
}%

Comment: @DanielFerreiraCastro: Sure. You never disclosed what `\Circle` and `\CIRCLE` are defined as, hence me taking some liberty to define something similar.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{x}
\newcounter{filled}
\newcommand{\dottedSkill}[2]{%
    %parameter 1 the filled dots
    %parameter 2 the max dots
    \setcounter{filled}{#1}%
    \forloop{x}{0}{\value{x} < #2}%
    {%
        \ifnum \thefilled < 1 
            $\circ$%\Circle
        \else 
            $\bullet$%\CIRCLE 
            \addtocounter{filled}{-1}%
        \fi
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\dottedSkill{2}{9}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first question to me if you need really the conditional. Only in case of XY problem (the true problem is not of make the loop works, but make a score with a macro with two arguments) here is a simpler approach:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\score[2][10]{
\makebox[#2em]{\cleaders\hbox to 1em{\Large\hss$\bullet$\hss}\hfill}%
\makebox[\dimexpr#1em-#2em]{\cleaders\hbox to 1em{\Large\hss$\circ$\hss}\hfill}\par} 
\begin{document}
\score[5]{0} 
\score[5]{1}
\score[5]{3}
\score[5]{5}
\score{0} 
\score{3} 
\score{6}
\score{10}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of you I was able to fine tune my solution to that.

I used as reference for the types of circle this link: https://aneescraftsmanship.com/circle-symbols%E2%97%8B%E2%97%8F%E2%97%8D%E2%97%97%E2%97%94%E2%97%99%E2%A6%BF-in-latex/

```
\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand{\EmptyDot}{\Circle}
\newcommand{\FilledDot}{$\CIRCLE$}

\newcommand{\dottedSkill}[2]{%
    %parameter 1 the filled dots
    %parameter 2 the max dots  
    \multido{\ix=1+1}{#1}{\FilledDot}%
    \ifnum#1<#2 \multido{\ix=#1+1}{\numexpr#2-#1}{\EmptyDot}\fi
}%
```