# How can I format a multicolumn document so a column vertical position is not messed up?

Tags: multicolumn, vertically

Thanks to the help provided on my question [How can I write a LaTex command with 'if'-'then'-'else'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/706451/how-can-i-write-a-latex-command-with-if-then-else/706453?noredirect=1#comment1756520_706453)

I was able to accomplish that.
[image: Latex character sheet for Vampire RPG]

I still need to adjust some positioning.  This is where I am fighting to solve and ask help

This is the code of the character sheet

```
\documentclass[HQ,english,Vampire]{WoDTeX}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\newcounter{squarecount}
\newcommand{\EmptyDot}{\Circle}
\newcommand{\FilledDot}{$\CIRCLE$}

\newcommand{\NewdottedSkill}[2]{%
    %parameter 1 the filled dots
    %parameter 2 the max dots  
    \multido{\ix=1+1}{#1}{\FilledDot}%
    \ifnum#1<#2 \multido{\ix=#1+1}{\numexpr#2-#1}{\EmptyDot\, \kern-0.2pt}\fi
}%

% Defina o comando \Humanity
\newcommand{\Humanity}[1]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            #1\\[-10.0pt]
            \rule{78pt}{0.4pt}\\
            \NewdottedSkill{0}{10}
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{center}
}

% Defina o comando \Willpower
\newcommand{\Willpower}[0]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \Squarerow
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\Squarerow}{%
    $\square$\, \kern-0.2pt 
    $\square$\, \kern-0.2pt 
    $\square$\, \kern-0.2pt 
    $\square$\, \kern-0.2pt 
    $\square$\, \kern-0.2pt 
    $\square$\, \kern-0.2pt 
    $\square$\, \kern-0.2pt 
    $\square$\, \kern-0.2pt 
    $\square$\, \kern-0.2pt $\square$\\
    \EmptyDot\, \kern-0.2pt 
    \EmptyDot\, \kern-0.2pt 
    \EmptyDot\, \kern-0.2pt 
    \EmptyDot\, \kern-0.2pt 
    \EmptyDot\, \kern-0.2pt 
    \EmptyDot\, \kern-0.2pt 
    \EmptyDot\, \kern-0.2pt 
    \EmptyDot\, \kern-0.2pt 
    \EmptyDot\, \kern-0.2pt \EmptyDot\\
}

\newcommand{\Bloodpool}[1]{%
    % parameter 1: total number of squares
    \setcounter{squarecount}{0} % Inicializa o contador
    \noindent
        \foreach \ix in {1,...,#1}{%
            $\square$\ifnum\ix<#1 \kern-1.0pt\fi % Adiciona espaço entre quadrados
            \stepcounter{squarecount}
            \ifnum\value{squarecount}=10 \\ % Inicia uma nova linha após 10 quadrados
            \setcounter{squarecount}{0} % Reinicia o contador para uma nova linha
            \fi
        }
}%

\newcommand{\experience}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[thick, black, solid] (-2.5,-1.7) rectangle ++(5,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Defina sua imagem de fundo aqui

\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=1,
    color=black,
    contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[inner sep=0] at (current page.center)
            {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{art/backgrounds/\genrePath/BG\isLQ}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \RaggedRight
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedright
            \PlayerCharGameInfo{Name}{Player}{Chronicle}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedright
            \PlayerCharGameInfo{Nature}{Demeanor}{Concept}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedright
            \PlayerCharGameInfo{Clan}{Generation}{Sire}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-2.5\baselineskip}
    \BigWoDSeperatorSheet{Attributes}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedright
            \centerline{Physical}\par
            \Attributes{Strength}{Dexterity}{Stamina}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \centering
            \centerline{Social}\par
            \Attributes{Charisma}{Manipulation}{Appearance}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedleft
            \centerline{Mental}\par
            \Attributes{Perception}{Intelligence}{Wits}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-2.5\baselineskip}
    \BigWoDSeperatorSheet{Abilities}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedright
            \centerline{Talents}\par
            \Abilities{Alertness}{Athletics}{Awarness}{Brawl}{Empathy}{Expression}{Intimidation}{Leadership}{Legendermain|Subterfuge}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \centering
            \centerline{Skills}\par
            \Abilities{Animal Ken}{Archery}{Commerce}{Crafts}{Etiquette}{Melee}{Performance}{Ride}{Stealth|Survival}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedleft
            \centerline{Knowledge}\par
            \Abilities{Academics}{Hearth Wisdom}{Investigation}{Law}{Linguistics}{Medicine}{Ocult}{Politics}{Seneschal|Science}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-2.5\baselineskip}
    \BigWoDSeperatorSheet{Advantages}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedright
            \centerline{Discipline}\par
            \Disciplines{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \centering
            \centerline{Background}\par
            \Backgrounds{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedleft
            \centerline{Virtues}\par
            \Virtues{Conscience/Conviction}{Self-Control/Instinct/}{Courage}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    %\vspace{-2.5\baselineskip}
    \BigWoDSeperatorSheetNonText{}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedright
            \SmallWoDSeperatorSheet{Other Traits}\par
            \OtherTraits{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}{\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_\kern-.14ex\_}
            %{OT9|OT10|OT11|OT12|OT13|OT14}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \centering
            \SmallWoDSeperatorSheet{Humanity / Path}\par
            \Humanity{Humanity}\par
            \SmallWoDSeperatorSheet{Willpower}\par
            \Willpower\par
            \SmallWoDSeperatorSheet{Bloodpool}\par
            \Bloodpool{40}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
            \raggedleft
            \SmallWoDSeperatorSheet{Health}\par
            \Healthlevel\par
            \SmallWoDSeperatorSheet{Experience}\par
            \experience
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is the code of the cls file named WoDTeX

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{WoDTeX}[2018/07/06 World of Darkness LaTeX]
\LoadClass[a4paper,twocolumns,oneside]{book}
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mwe,tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{intcalc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}% http://ctan.org/pkg/contour
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{xstring}

\definecolor{coverGold}{RGB}{235,186,118}
\definecolor{coverFontTitleColor}{RGB}{253, 215, 215}
\definecolor{tablebackground}{RGB}{255,255,255}

%\rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{white}
%\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}}
%\newcommand{\firstColumn}[1]{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}}

\DeclareOption{portuguese}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{artigo}}
\DeclareOption{english}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\DeclareOption{LQ}{\providecommand{\isLQ}{_LQ}}
\DeclareOption{HQ}{\providecommand{\isLQ}{}}
\DeclareOption{Vampire}{
    \providecommand{\genrePath}{Vampire}
    \providecommand{\genreFont}{Delavan}
    \providecommand{\titleFont}{DeRoos}
    \providecommand{\genreFrontTextColor}{black!10}
    \providecommand{\genreGeometryTop}{2.5cm}
    \providecommand{\genreGeometryBottom}{3.5cm}
    \providecommand{\genreGeometryInner}{2.5cm}
    \providecommand{\genreGeometryOuter}{2.5cm}
    \providecommand{\genreChapterSpacing}{6cm}
    \providecommand{\genreTOCSpacing}{10cm}
    \providecommand{\genreLeftMargin}{1.8cm}
    \providecommand{\genreChapTitlePos}{.01\paperwidth,-.01\paperheight}
    \providecommand{\genreCreditsPos}{.352\paperwidth,-.404\paperheight}
    \providecommand{\genreTOCTitleColor}{white!80!black}
    \providecommand{\genreTOCBodyColor}{white!80!black}
}%end of Vampire Specifics

\ProcessOptions\relax
\ExecuteOptions{english,LQ,Vampire}%setting Default
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=\genreGeometryTop, bottom=\genreGeometryBottom, outer=\genreGeometryOuter, inner=\genreGeometryInner, left=\genreLeftMargin]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shadings,decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\newcommand{\theFont             }{\genreFont}
\newcommand{\theFontSection      }{\genreFont}
\newcommand{\theFontSubSection   }{\genreFont}
\newcommand{\theFontSubSubSection}{\genreFont}

\newcommand{\coverTitleFont}{\titleFont}


%\newcommand{\EmptyDot}{\Circle}
%\newcommand{\FilledDot}{$\CIRCLE$}

\providecommand{\SmallWoDSeperatorSheet}[1]
{
    \center
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {
            \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]
            {
                art/sidebar/\genrePath/SidebarSheet\isLQ
            }
        };
        \node [anchor=center, align=center, fill=white, inner sep=5pt] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\providecommand{\BigWoDSeperatorSheet}[1]
{
    \center
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{
            art/sidebar/\genrePath/SidebarBrokenSheet\isLQ}
    };
    \node [anchor=center, align=center]at (0,-2.8mm){
        \textbf{
            \fontspec{
                \theFont
            }
            \fontsize{23}{20}\selectfont #1}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\providecommand{\BigWoDSeperatorSheetNonText}[0]
{
    \center
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{
                art/sidebar/\genrePath/SidebarSheet\isLQ}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setmainfont{Goudy Old Style}
% Comando que cria o grupo de atributos com a fila de dots
\newcommand{\PlayerCharGameInfo}[3]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#1} & \\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#2} & \\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#3} & 
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{center}
}

% Comando que cria o grupo de atributos com a fila de dots
\newcommand{\Attributes}[3]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#1} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#2} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#3} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\dottedSkill}[2]{%
    %parameter 1 the filled dots
    %parameter 2 the max dots  
    \multido{\ix=1+1}{#1}{\FilledDot}%
    \ifnum#1<#2 \multido{\ix=#1+1}{\numexpr#2-#1}{\EmptyDot}\fi
}%

\newcommand{\Healthlevel}[0]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\hskip 0.5em}c@{\hskip 0.5em}c@{}}
            Bruised & & $\square$ \\
            Hurt & -1 & $\square$ \\
            Injured & -1 & $\square$ \\
            Wounded & -2 & $\square$ \\
            Mauled & -2 & $\square$ \\
            Crippled & -5 & $\square$ \\
            Incapacitated & & $\square$ \\
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\Abilities}[9]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#1} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#2} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#3} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#4} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#5} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#6} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#7} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#8} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \ComplAbilities{#9}{|}
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{center}
}


% Comando intermediário para dividir a string
\newcommand{\ComplAbilities}[2]{%
    \noindent
    \makebox[4.7em][l]{\StrBefore{#1}{#2}} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
    \makebox[4.7em][l]{\StrBehind{#1}{#2}} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}
}


\newcommand{\Disciplines}[6]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#1} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#2} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#3} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#4} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#5} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#6} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\Backgrounds}[6]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#1} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#2} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#3} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#4} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#5} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
            \makebox[4.7em][l]{#6} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\Virtues}[3]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \makebox[7.6em][l]{#1} & \dottedSkill{1}{5}\\[11.5pt]
            \makebox[7.6em][l]{#2} & \dottedSkill{1}{5}\\[11.5pt]
            \makebox[7.6em][l]{#3} & \dottedSkill{1}{5}\\[11.5pt]
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{center}
}


\newcommand{\OtherTraits}[8]{%
    \noindent
\begin{center}
    \vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \makebox[4.7em][l]{#1} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
        \makebox[4.7em][l]{#2} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
        \makebox[4.7em][l]{#3} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
        \makebox[4.7em][l]{#4} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
        \makebox[4.7em][l]{#5} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
        \makebox[4.7em][l]{#6} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
        \makebox[4.7em][l]{#7} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
        \makebox[4.7em][l]{#8} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
        %\ComplAbilities{#9}{|}
    \end{tabular}%
\end{center}
}

% Comando intermediário para dividir a string
\newcommand{\ComplOtherTraits}[2]{%
    \noindent
    \makebox[4.7em][l]{\StrBefore{#1}{#2}} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}\\
    \makebox[4.7em][l]{\StrBehind{#1}{#2}} & \dottedSkill{1}{10}
}
\endinput
```

Resources used

Background
[image]

Sidebar
[image: Sidebar]

Sidebar not broken

[image: Sidebar not broken]

**Question**: I would like to have all the last block aligned in the same way that other blocks above are.  How can it be done?

Comment: It is not too clear of what is the desired the output?

Comment: It was clear in a numbered list but I managed to fix and edit the topic to reflect my question that is now simpler.

Comment: Have you tried to change the `minipage[b]` to `minipage[t]`? Only in the three minipages that you have in the bottom

Comment: It works better but I am still having misalignments

Comment: For me it gets quite well aligned when I change the  `\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]` from  `\SmallWoDSeperatorSheet`  to `\includegraphics[width=0.99\textwidth]`. I post it as a comment as I am not sure where the issue is, and I do not have your fonts installed on my system (I changed them to Arial). There are "paragraph too wide" errors everywhere, so maybe it has to do with that.